# Initializing a property in a viewmodel with values from an observableproperty

Tags: c#, maui

I have a MAUI application and transferring data from one view to another via ObservableProperty.
I would like to initialize another property with some values from this ObservableProperty, but at the moment the viewmodel is initialized all values in the ObservableProperty are null.

How can I do this?

```csharp
 [QueryProperty(nameof(JobDetails), "getJobDto")]
 public partial class JobViewModel : BaseViewModel
 {
     [ObservableProperty]
     RapportFieldWorkDto jobDetails = new();

     CreateRapportReturnDto returnElm;

     public JobViewModel()
     {
         returnElm = new(jobDetails.RapportFieldId, jobDetails.WorkId, jobDetails.GetWorkDto.Name, jobDetails.RapportDate);
     }
 }
```

Comment: It’s Observable, so you can subscribe to the PropertyChanged event

Comment: Why do you need to transfer? Declare a model that's in a service or a singleton and dependency inject that same model everywhere. So, every view will see the same instance of the model. No need to make copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tip with the PropertyChanged event is doing the job. Thanks to Jason

```csharp
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? JobDetailsChanged;

partial void OnJobDetailsChanged(RapportFieldWorkDto value)
{
    returnElm = new(value.RapportFieldId, value.WorkId, value.GetWorkDto.Name, value.RapportDate);
}
```